# Center a recyclerView card item in a specific view after scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a slot game with a vertical RecyclerView and a button, when the user hit that button, it automatically scrolls the list. Meanwhile, in my main activity XML, I have a view with a gray background. How can I make it so that when the RecyclerView finishes scrolling after 4 seconds, any item in the list stays centred in the view that is in the middle of the screen?

this is my adapter

```
class ImageAdapter (private val imageList: List<ImageItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    companion object {
        const val LOOP_COUNT_FOR_INFINITE_SCROLL = 100
    }
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imageView: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card)
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.activity_list, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val imageItem = imageList[position % imageList.size]
        holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(imageItem.imageResId)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return imageList.count()* LOOP_COUNT_FOR_INFINITE_SCROLL
    }
    fun getRealItemCount(): Int {
        return imageList.count()
    }

}
```

and in my MainActivity class i have this function setting the timer

```
private fun setCountDown() {
        val countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(8000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                AppConfig.miConstanteGlobal += 90.0f
                startStoping()
            }

            override fun onFinish() {

/*
How should the on finish method be so that any item in the list
 is centered in the activity_main.xml view after scrolling
*/


// i tried this code but  not working

                recyclerView!!.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
                val snapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
                val adapter = ImageAdapter(imageList)
                snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(null)
  

            }
        }
        countDownTimer.start()
    }
```

should like something like that after scrolling
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZIu3.png)